# Should [ios-widget] be merged into [widgetkit]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

In iOS 14 Apple introduced Widgets which can be implemented with SwiftUI and WidgetKit.

For the last couple of months I was answering questions tagged [widgetkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/widgetkit). However, I've recently realised there is a [ios-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-widget) tag as well.

Description and usage:

- [widgetkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/widgetkit) - 154 questions (as of now)

  > Use for WidgetKit introduced in iOS 14 and macOS Catalyst 14
- [ios-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-widget) - 7 questions (as of now)

  > Refers to widgets that can be added to the iOS home screen

There is also a *generic* [widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/widget) tag which itself has no particular use but if used with [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift)/[swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui) seems to be OK.

It looks like [ios-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-widget) can be represented by [swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui)+[widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/widget) but [widgetkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/widgetkit) is irreplaceable as it's dedicated to a specific framework.

Whenever I see an incorrectly tagged question about SwiftUI Widgets I always add [widgetkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/widgetkit). It looks like [ios-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-widget) is not necessary.

My question is: should [ios-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-widget) be **merged into** [widgetkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/widgetkit)?

Comment: This seems like as good a candidate for synonymization as there can be. It definitely falls into the ["common, alternate spellings or phrasings"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ios-widget/synonyms) category.